# phpStorm: global project favorites

Tags: phpstorm, favorites

i found out there's a favorites toolbar in phpstorm but it seems like it's only storing the current project's favorites.
is there a way having a global favorites projects/folders list which is accessible from all projects?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably kind of opportunity is absent. IntelliJ work only with one project **per window** so it show you *Favorites* only from this scope.

There is no mentions about it in official [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/managing-your-project-favorites.html).

Feel free to post a [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).